# Sqlcmd: 'var=1': Invalid argument. using Bash Script

Tags: bash, sqlcmd

This is my first post in stackoverflow :D

I'm having a problem in passing variables in sql file using sqlcmd.

```
sqlcmd -S "$host" -U "$username" -P "$password" -d "$dbname" -s "║" -v test=1 -i $productQuery -h -1 | while IFS="," read -r row
do
 # some stuff here..    
done
```

It has error "Sqlcmd: 'test=1': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.". Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Do you still get the same error message, if you move the `-v test=1` in front of the -S option, immediately after _sqlcmd_.

Comment: Yes. Error is still there...

Comment: Did you check for hex characters in the area of -v, which might display as a white space, but confuse `sqlcmd`? If you manually type justs `sqlcmd -v test=1`, and nothing else, do you get this error message too?

Comment: Thanks for the response @user1934428. I tried using in bash command line and it works well. I don't understand why it gives error when using it in my bash script.

Comment: Did you check for hidden characters, as I recommended? Also, if you copy&paste the command from your text editor into the command line, does the error occur then?

Comment: Finally, what is this funny character which you specify as a separator with your `-s` option? Though it shouldn't harm, it is unusual - so, just for a test, if you remove the `-s "║"` part, do you still get the same error message?

Comment: Yes, I retype all the command to make sure there is no hidden character and remove the `-s "║"` parameter but error message is still there. Error is occurring when `| while IFS="," read -r row.. ` is present

Comment: By the way the reason I used `-s "║"` as separator that I'm having also a problem when splitting column values when I use common characters like `, | - `

Comment: So, if you keep `-v test=1`, but remove the `|while ...` part, the error goes away??? So, what happens, if you don't pipe into `while`, but redirect the output to a file,i.e.  `... -i $productQuery -h -1 > output_file`. Still an error?

Comment: Hi @user1934428. I solved my problem using different approach, but your suggestion is a good solution, really appreciated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `|while ...` is causing the error. I came up with different solution to solved my problem. Thanks to @user1934428